# AWS public IP list doesn't contain addresses that it should

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have problems understanding how the amazon's public ip list [here](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json) works. For example, when I query IP `35.165.39.114`, it shows that the IP is allocated to amazon:

```
NetRange:       35.152.0.0 - 35.183.255.255
CIDR:           35.152.0.0/13, 35.176.0.0/13, 35.160.0.0/12
```

But the IP list only has these:

```
{
  "ip_prefix": "34.248.0.0/13",
  "region": "eu-west-1",
  "service": "AMAZON"
},
{
  "ip_prefix": "35.153.0.0/16",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "service": "AMAZON"
},
```

So this IP is not included in the IP list file? Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`35.160.0.0/13` is a [CIDR Range](http://software77.net/cidr-101.html). `35.165.39.114` falls between the range.

```
Starting IP:   35.160.0.1           
Ending IP:   35.167.255.254     
Total No of IPs: 524286
```

There are CIDR calculators[[1]](http://jodies.de/ipcalc)[[2]](http://magic-cookie.co.uk/iplist.html) which will help you to find the ranges.

Comment: Does it though? I used [this one](https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr) and it says Last IP 34.255.255.255. The one on your link #1 says HostMax: 34.255.255.254 . The #2 does not allow /13

Comment: 34.255.255.255 is reserved by the network for broadcasting and 34.248.0.0 for network + AWS also reserves 2 IPS. Yes, it takes a lot of time to calculate /13, you try with smaller cidr nos, just to get an idea.

Comment: No I meant that the calculators say this CIDR range is `34.248.0.0` to `34.255.255.254` (or 5). `35.165.39.114` doesn't fall into this range, right?

Comment: Ok, Got it, I pasted the wrong IP. you should be using the cidr 35.153.0.0/16

Comment: Got it now, thanks (guess I should be using 35.160.0.0/13 as the edited answer says though)